# How to weaken the connection component

Tags: graph, arangodb

I want to add a counter when traversing the graph，

```
for x in mycollection
for v,e,p in 1..1 any x._id graph'mygraph'
return v
```

I want to add a counter after traversing the collection，I want to go through the graph counter after traversal plus 1.

```
let count=1
for x in mycollection
for v,e,p in 1..1 any x._id graph'mygraph'
return v
count++
```

I am not interested in the length of the collection, I just want to traverse the graph after each, the counter is added 1
I wrote two unfinished js files，
In fact, I was trying to figure out the weak connected component in my graph，code show as below

```
'use strict';
function connectionGraph(vertex,count1,collection,graphName) {
var db = require('@arangodb').db;

      var q2 =  "        for v,e,p in 1..1 any @vt._id graph @graph \n" +
                "            update x with{label:@count} in @@ttv \n" +
                "            filter v.label!=@count \n" +
                "                 return MYFUNCTION::dfs(v,@count,@@ttv)";
 var param = {vt:vertex,count:count1,@ttv:collection,graph:graphName}

 db._query(q2,param);
}

module.exports = connectionGraph;

'use strict';
function connection(c,collection,graphName) {
var db = require('@arangodb').db;
int c = 1;
var query = "for x in @@tv \n"
"for v,e,p in 1..1 any x._id graph @graph \n" +
"   update x with{label:@count} in @@tv \n" +
" filter v.label!=@count \n" +
" return MYFUNCTION::dfs(v,@count,@@collection,@graph)";
var param = {count:c,@tv:collection,graph:graphName};
db._query(query,param);
}
module.exports = connection;
```

I do not know how to write, can you help me?

I just wanted to find the weakly connected component of a graph.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm named "connected components" to find weakly connected components in a graph is available for ArangoDB.
It can be executed with:

```
var pregel = require("@arangodb/pregel");
pregel.start("connectedcomponents", "graphname")
```

The algorithm is documented at:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/data-science/pregel/pregel-algorithms/#connected-components